# Effekt von Frageumkehrung: "Sie haben noch Fragen?"

Tags: sentence-structure, question

Welchen Effekt hat die Umkehrung unten?

> Sie möchten Ihre Nummer ändern? (Kein Problem...)

(Das lese ich oft in Werbung.) Anstatt:

> Möchten Sie Ihre Nummer ändern?

was ich als grammatikalisch korrekt wusste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es stimmt, dass ein reiner Fragesatz

> Möchten Sie Ihre Nummer ändern?

lauten würde. Diese Frage lässt jedoch die Antwort völlig offen.

Möchte man ausdrücken, dass man ziemlich sicher ist, dass die Aussage zutrifft, wird mitunter der Aussagesatz als Frage gestellt, wie du das beobachtet hast:

> Sie möchten Ihren Namen ändern?

Meist taucht das in den folgenden Fällen auf:

- Man ist sich ziemlich sicher, dass man richtig liegt, möchte das Gegenüber jedoch auffordern, im Zweifelsfall zu widersprechen, falls nicht.
- Es handelt sich um eine rhetorische Frage, auf deren vermuteter Antwort normalerweise direkt im Anschluss aufgebaut wird.

Comment: I do not agree. Although the questions have a different flavour, both require an answer (yes or no) which is the same in cases. The variant "Sie möchten Ihren Namen ändern?" suggests in fact that a confirmation is expected, but this is irrelevant. The answer can be no.

Comment: @PaulFrost: The answer *can* be no. But if I'd reasonably expect no for an answer, I most likely wouldn't ask "Sie möchten Ihren Namen ändern?", but "Möchten Sie Ihren Namen ändern?"

Answer (score 1):

Beides ist korrekt, die Haltung des Fragenden zur Antwort ist verschieden:

> Haben Sie noch Fragen?

Dies ist neutral und keine Antwortmöglichkeit wird impliziert oder vorausgesetzt.

> Sie haben noch Fragen?

Diese Form drückt aus, dass die Frage eher rethorischer Natur ist und der Fragende erwartet, dass die Frage positiv beantwortet wird. Üblicherweise wird der Sprecher oder Text dann auf keine Antwort warten sondern sofort damit fortfahren, eben jene Frage zu beantworten. Im Fall von Texten, insbesondere von Werbung will und kann man nicht auf eine Antwort warten und wird dann gleich erzählen, was der Leser tun soll (hier, um Fragen beantwortet zu bekommen). Davon abgesehen kann natürlich auch erste, neutrale Frageform rethorisch verwendet werden - aber das ergibt sich dann nur aus dem Kontext der Nutzung.

---

Both are correct, the attitude of the person asking is different:

> Haben Sie noch Fragen?

This is the usual, neutral form which does not assume or presume an answer in one way or another.

> Sie haben noch Fragen?

This way the question is more rethorical, and a positive answer is expected - and usually the speaker or text then immediately continues to address this without waiting for an answer. In the case of written communication as in ads, this form can be used on grounds that a leaflet cannot wait for a reply anyway. So they ask and then proceed to tell what reader shall do if there are any questions (though using the open question is fine, too).

Comment: Die Frage war auf Deutsch gestellt.

Comment: Korrekt. Und das fällt mir natürlich erst auf nachdem ich die Antwort fertig habe ;)

Comment: Ich kenn das Gefühl :)

Comment: @planetmaker: Having the answer in both languages is convenient for me, but I wouldn't expect anyone to write out an answer twice just for my sake. One nitpick, "both" is always plural in English. I know *beides* can be singular in German. I'll go ahead and make the correction.

Comment: @RDBury thanks! I wouldn't have written it twice, had I written it in the correct language in the first place. But what would be the point of deleting it in the other? :)